# Find out whether version-specific or generic kernel was selected during Debian installation

Tags: debian, kernel

How can I find out on a running Debian system whether a [version-specific](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2014/05/msg01953.html) (e.g. `linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64`) or generic (e.g. `linux.image-amd64`) was selected when the Debian installer presented the choice at setup time (in "Installing the base system")?

I understand that `uname -r` would always return the specific version number (e.g. `3.16.0-4-amd64`).

Comment: There might be something in `debconf-get-selections`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the `linux-image-amd64` package is installed.

There are numerous ways to do this, including:

```
$ dpkg -l linux-image-amd64
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  linux-image-am 4.14+88      amd64        Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-packag
```

and:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections linux-image-amd64
linux-image-amd64       install
```

These "generic" packages are almost empty (aside from some files in e.g. `/usr/share/doc/linux-image-64`) that depend on the package containing the latest kernel version.  E.g. the version in debian unstable at the moment has:

```
Depends: linux-image-4.14.0-2-amd64
```

So, installing or upgrading `linux-image-amd64` will cause `linux-image-4.14.0-2-amd64` to be installed.

If you have `dlocate` installed, you can list all installed kernel packages (and related packages, such as dkms module packages) with `dlocate -k` (simple list) or `dlocate -K` (detailed list, almost identical to `dpkg -l` output).

e.g. on my current desktop machine:

```
$ dlocate -k
linux-doc-4.12
linux-doc-4.14
linux-headers-4.12.0-2-amd64
linux-headers-4.12.0-2-common
linux-headers-4.14.0-2-amd64
linux-headers-4.14.0-2-common
linux-headers-amd64
linux-image-4.12.0-2-amd64
linux-image-4.14.0-2-amd64
linux-image-amd64
linux-kbuild-4.12
linux-kbuild-4.14
nvidia-kernel-dkms
spl-dkms
zfs-dkms
```

Comment: When I run `dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image` it reports a generic `linux-image-amd64` as well as three version-specific `linux-image-*`'s, all of them with indication `install`, i.e. not installed. This is for an (oldish) Debian 7.10 box. What is also weird is that `dpkg -l linux-image-amd64` reports `Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold | Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend |/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)`.

Comment: "install" does **NOT** mean "not installed".   It means either "installed" or "flagged for installation".   if you have the generic and 3 version specific linux-images then they will all be installed (as I said, linux-image-amd64 depends on specific versioned kernel packages so causes them to be installed - without a lot of pointless messing around with your system, you can not install linux-image-amd64 without a specific versioned linux-image- package too)

Comment: the point is that if the linux-image-amd64 generic version is installed, it means that the sysadmin either chose to install a generic kernel when they first installed the system, or knew/learned enough about their system to achieve exactly the same end-result by installing it manually.

Comment: @rookie099 It is better to install the `linux-image` meta-package because it will install the latest available kernel version (as dependency )  from the debian repository .